# Docker image does not run

Tags: spring, docker, docker-image

I just downloaded a new docker image. When I try to run it I get this log on my console

```
Setting Active Processor Count to 4
Calculating JVM memory based on 381456K available memory
unable to calculate memory configuration
fixed memory regions require 654597K which is greater than 381456K available for allocation: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M, -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=142597K, -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M, -Xss1M * 250 threads
```

Please, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have multiple services and you are going to start them at a time. The issue is related to memory which docker and spring boot uses.

Try this:

```
environment:
      - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx128000K
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 800m
```

You have to provide memory which I mentioned in the  .yaml file syntax.

While at the time of startup each service takes lot of memory, so there is no memory remaining for rest of the services and because of that other services starts failing with the memory related message.